# ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.Provisioning Error'>): Provision failed - Provisioning Error:

Tags: server, samba

How solve this error:

```
root@BDC:~# samba-tool domain provision --interactive --function-level=2008_R2 --use-rfc2307 --option="interfaces=lo eth0" --option="bind interfaces only=yes"
Realm [BDDC]:
 Domain [BDDC]:
 Server Role (dc, member, standalone) [dc]:
 DNS backend (SAMBA_INTERNAL, BIND9_FLATFILE, BIND9_DLZ, NONE) [SAMBA_INTERNAL]:
 DNS forwarder IP address (write 'none' to disable forwarding) [103.8.46.5]:
Administrator password:
Invalid administrator password.
Administrator password:
Invalid administrator password.
Administrator password:
Retype password:
ERROR(<class 'samba.provision.ProvisioningError'>): Provision failed - ProvisioningError: guess_names: Realm 'BDDC' must not be equal to short domain name 'BDDC'!
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/netcmd/domain.py", line 434, in run
    nosync=ldap_backend_nosync, ldap_dryrun_mode=ldap_dryrun_mode)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 2022, in provision
    sitename=sitename, rootdn=rootdn, domain_names_forced=(samdb_fill == FILL_DRS))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/samba/provision/__init__.py", line 638, in guess_names
    raise ProvisioningError("guess_names: Realm '%s' must not be equal to short domain name '%s'!" % (realm, domain))
```

Answer (score 0):

Specify a valid domain name; it needs to have a dot in it. E.g.:

- Realm: BDDC.COM
- Domain: bddc.com

(This causes the short domain name to be "BDDC", and thus it won't be the same as the realm - "BDDC.COM")